# Remove duplicate keys from a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I am new to Python, and I am currently stumped by this problem:

I have a list of dictionaries generated `csv.DictReader`. I have created the list with the function as follows:

```
def csvToDictList(filename):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(filename, 'rb'))

    list = []
    for row in reader:
        list.append(row)

    return (list, reader.fieldnames)
```

This worked great, but CSV file I am processing has duplicate columns, so I end up with a dictionary like:

```
[
{'Column1': 'Value1', 'Column2': 'Value2', ... <some unique columns and values> ..., 'Column1': 'Value1', 'Column2': 'Value2'},
...
{'Column1': 'Value1N', 'Column2': 'Value2N', ... <some unique columns and values> ..., 'Column1': 'Value1N', 'Column2': 'Value2N'}
]
```

**My main question is how do I remove duplicate columns out of this dictionary list?**

I thought about iterating over each key, and then removing the column when I detect a duplicate key name with something like this:

```
def removeColumn(dictList, colName):
    for row in dictList:
        del row[colName]
```

But, won't that remove both columns? Should I be operating on the hash-keys of the dictionary? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT :** The duplicates I was seeing were actually present in the `reader.fieldnames` list. So, I was assuming the dictionaries contained these columns as well, which was an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Python dictionaries don't have duplicate keys - a subsequent write to a key will blow away what was previously present there.  What is the unedited content of one of your rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like duplicate keys in a dictionary.

If you have more columns with the same name, DictReader will take only the last one (overwriting the previous ones).

For the following CSV file:

```
a,b,c,a,b
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

the DictReader will return following dicts:

```
{'a': '4', 'c': '3', 'b': '5'}
{'a': '9', 'c': '8', 'b': '10'}
```

thus throwing the previous values for `a` and `b` columns away.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the reader.fieldnames, and the duplicates were still present there, but not in the data. I tried your small test, and sure enough the duplicates are gone, which is all I care about.